# Autolayout resizes my views

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout, xib

In my xib I've set some very simple constraints.

There are 3 buttons

```
 ________
|   __   |
|  |__|  |
|   __   |
|  |__|  |
|   __   |
|  |__|  |
|________|
```

- They have size constraints set to constant width = 100, height = 80.
- They have spacing between them set to a constant 50.
- They have matching leading edges and trailing edges.
- They have heights equal to each other and widths equal to each other.
- The center button is set to center X and Y with it's superview
- The two other buttons are set to center X with the middle button.

Everything looks nice and clean in the xib.
I run the app and the buttons are aligned and centered in the middle of the view as expected, but their widths and heights are all very tiny (~20 pixels).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hi awesome-o sounds like conflicting requirements - are these the ONLY constraints on this view?

Comment: what else is there in the superview.. what's the frame size of the view when VC's viewDidLoad is called?

Comment: check the height of this view and the priorities of the constraints. i bet as the OS tries to fulfill the other constraints, the height becomes smaller and smaller.. especially if its on iphone4/4s